# Dummy Variable Function

Tags: r, function, tibble

I have to write a function that will take a dataframe/tibble as an argument and a factor variable as another argument and will create dummy variable for that factor and append them to the end fo the dataframe, while making sure to deal with cases where someone doesn’t put in a tibble/dataframe as first argument and a factor as second argument. There must also be a third argument where the user can decide whether or not they want to drop the original variable and just keep the dummies or keep all three. Make this third argument have a default value of TRUE.

I have the below outline so far but it doesn't work the way it is intended. I also have no clue how to code the third variable in the function. The sample code below it is what was given to test that the code works properly. Not sure how to model the function around it.

```
create_dummies<- function(df,fac_var,or_var=TRUE){
  df<- tibble(
    sex = sample(c('Male', 'Female', NA), 20, T),
    voted = sample(c('Yes', 'No', NA), 20, T))
  schtyp <- sample(0:1, 20, replace = TRUE)
  fac_var <- factor(schtyp, labels = c("Male", "Female"))
  #or_var<-
}

set.seed(1234)
test <- tibble(
  sex = sample(c('Male', 'Female', NA), 20, T),
  voted = sample(c('Yes', 'No', NA), 20, T)
)
test <- test %>% mutate(
  sex = parse_factor(
    sex, levels = c('Male', 'Female'), include_na = F
  ),
  voted = parse_factor(voted, levels = c('Yes', 'No'), include_na = F)
)
create_dummies(test, 'sex', T)
create_dummies(test, 'sex', F)
create_dummies(test, 'voted', T)
create_dummies(test, 'voted', F)
```

Comment: Your function takes a tibble object 'df', then it is not really used i.e. you are creating a tibble again inside the function.  Not clear why  you want to do that.  Also, if you want to create a new column assign it to the dataset. i.e. `df$fac_var <- ...` and return the `df`

Answer (score 1):

## Create function with 3 arguments to make dummies

```r
# library(tidyverse)

make_dummies <- function(df, var_input, keep_it = TRUE) {
  
  df_derived <- 
  tibble::as_tibble(df) |>
    dplyr::mutate(aux_01 = {{ var_input }},
                  aux_02 = 1L) |>
    tidyr::pivot_wider(
      names_from = aux_01 ,
      values_from = aux_02,
      values_fill = 0
    )
  
  if (keep_it == TRUE) {
    df_derived
  } else {
    df_derived |> dplyr::select( !{{ var_input }} )
  }
  
}
```

## Exemples:

```r
make_dummies(HairEyeColor, Sex)

#> # A tibble: 32 × 6
#>    Hair  Eye   Sex       n  Male Female
#>    <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <int>  <int>
#>  1 Black Brown Male     32     1      0
#>  2 Brown Brown Male     53     1      0
#>  3 Red   Brown Male     10     1      0
#>  4 Blond Brown Male      3     1      0
#>  5 Black Blue  Male     11     1      0
#>  6 Brown Blue  Male     50     1      0
#>  7 Red   Blue  Male     10     1      0
#>  8 Blond Blue  Male     30     1      0
#>  9 Black Hazel Male     10     1      0
#> 10 Brown Hazel Male     25     1      0
#> # … with 22 more rows

make_dummies(HairEyeColor, Sex, keep_it = FALSE)

#> # A tibble: 32 × 5
#>    Hair  Eye       n  Male Female
#>    <chr> <chr> <dbl> <int>  <int>
#>  1 Black Brown    32     1      0
#>  2 Brown Brown    53     1      0
#>  3 Red   Brown    10     1      0
#>  4 Blond Brown     3     1      0
#>  5 Black Blue     11     1      0
#>  6 Brown Blue     50     1      0
#>  7 Red   Blue     10     1      0
#>  8 Blond Blue     30     1      0
#>  9 Black Hazel    10     1      0
#> 10 Brown Hazel    25     1      0
#> # … with 22 more rows

sessioninfo::session_info()[["platform"]][["version"]]
#> [1] "R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

## Alternative

If you did not have to make a function, there is a package called `fastDummies` that make it easy:

```r
# install.packages("fastDummies")
library(fastDummies)

HairEyeColor |>
  dummy_columns(select_columns = "Sex") |>
  head()

#>    Hair   Eye  Sex  N Sex_Female Sex_Male
#> 1 Black Brown Male 32          0        1
#> 2 Brown Brown Male 53          0        1
#> 3   Red Brown Male 10          0        1
#> 4 Blond Brown Male  3          0        1
#> 5 Black  Blue Male 11          0        1
#> 6 Brown  Blue Male 50          0        1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it has to be a function from scratch. I cannot use fastDummies or model.matrix() or anything that does it automatically.

Comment: Do you really need to install a package? `cbind(HairEyeColor, model.matrix(~Sex+0, HairEyeColor))`